# Java adding CC and BCC to send email program

Tags: java, email

I have the following codes, which is able to send mail from gmail. Question is at which part should I add the CC and BCC receiver so that they too can receive the mail.

I did a search and found some help here but it doesnt work on my program, i get error on the BCC and CC list.

> ```
>     InternetAddress[] myToList = InternetAddress.parse("gopi.mani@xyz.com,Maimsa.SF@xyz.com"); 
>     InternetAddress[] myBccList = InternetAddress.parse("Usha.B@xyz.com"); 
>     InternetAddress[] myCcList = InternetAddress.parse("NEHA.SIVA@xyz.com"); 
>
>
>     message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,myToList); 
>     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC,myBccList); 
>     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,myCcList);
> ```

### Code

```
 import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.internet.*;
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class SendEmail {
    
        private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.gmail.com";
        private static final int SMTP_HOST_PORT = 587;
        private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "sender@gmail.com";
        private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD = "";
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SendEmail se = new SendEmail();
            se.mail();
        }
    
        public void mail() throws Exception {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    
            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            mailSession.setDebug(true);
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            message.setSubject("Testing SMTP From Java");
    
            message.setContent("Hello world", "text/plain");
    
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("receiver@gmail.com"));
    
            transport.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.addRecipient

Comment: That's a *compile* error. Fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,myToList);
```

to:

```
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,myToList);
```

and then:

```
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

Comment: I got the error for myToList, it say cannot be converted to address by method ?!???

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: crap...this is funny I got error just now when i use set , after i change to add the error is gone...and now i change back to set. it works again

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but this could help you take a different approach. 

I'm a fan of the commons email jar: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/

You can send an email like this which is much more straight forward to read.

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

-Rick